# Background Image Issue with IOS

Tags: codenameone

I am using the "FlatBlueTheme" and I modified the Form to have a background image.

On Android: background image shows elegantly
On Simulator: background image shows elegantly
On IPad Mini (32bit) : background images shows on first form -- when switching to a new Form().show() the background of the form goes solid black.

Comment: Kindly add details of how you're currently setting the background image.

Comment: Using Theme Editor --> Form --> Background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will happen if the image is either really big and thus exceeds the GPU threshold on iOS (typically 4096 pixels but this can vary).

This can also happen if the format of the image isn't supported on iOS e.g. jpeg2000 possibly gif or some other format. Make sure you use either PNG or regular JPEG.

You see the image initially because of the screenshot process described in the [iOS section of the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-ios.html).

Comment: The image was rather large.  I added to the theme as a multiimage and all is well now.